# Nodejs require('../controllers/UserController.js') returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

im trying to build a web application and using nodeJS and mongoose (along with other modules). The module dependency looks something like this [Image showing project heirarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaECf.png)

I have an Accessor.js module that is basically where everything comes together and bind with each other, so for example say mongoose object need to be shared by all models, all such bindings and dependencies are handled here.

This is what my Accessor.js file looks like

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp');

var userModel = new require('../models/User.js')(mongoose);
var userController = new require('../controllers/UserController.js')(userModel);

console.log('USERCONTROLLER '+userController); //this shows value to be undefined

module.exports = {
  getUserController : function(){
    console.log("RETURNING USERCONTROLLER : "+ userController);
    return userController;
  }
};
```

I commented out the line that shows the value of the UserController object to be 
undefined

and this is how my UserController.js file looks like

```
var UserController = function(userModel)
{
  this.userModel = userModel;
}
UserController.prototype.getUsersCount = function(){
  return userModel.getUsersCount();
}
UserController.prototype.isUsernameAvailable = function(username){
  ...
  ...
};

module.exports = UserController;
```

i tried to look on the internet on what could because of this issue, some posts suggested that cyclic dependency might cause such issue but thats not the case here. I even tried different ways to implement it inside UserController.js, as a object and as a constructor object but nothing works for me, please help :)

Comment: Did you try requiring in the module in one statement and then creating a new instance in other. Plus `console.log('USERCONTROLLER '+userController);` seems a bit off. Can you try just logging the `userController`?

Comment: yes, tried it already and its still the same. The reason for using console.log(..) is earlier to spot the error, i had to perform various steps only to get following error : Cannot read property 'getUserId' of undefined.

Comment: hmm ok. Did you check if the module that you are requiring is in correct folder as well. For example, in this case the `userController` is one level above from Accessor.js and inside `controllers` folder. Is that right?

Comment: Thanks for help, the issue is solved ( i forgot the brackets, see answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use brackets in require statement.

corrected:

```js
var userController = new (require('../controllers/UserController.js'))(userModel);
```